# When delete button is pushed on gridview throws Must declare the scalar variable "@Content"

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, formview

I am trying to enable deleting in grid view. When you run this code and press the delete button you get the error Must declare the scalar variable "@Content".

**Code**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Content" HeaderText="Content" SortExpression="Content" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ImportantNews]" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ImportantNews] WHERE [Content] = @Content AND [Title] = @Title">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="string"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Content" Type="string"/>
    </DeleteParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Please note I am using Asp.net 2.0

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Content,Title"........
```

Comment: This might make more sense. I haven't used a GridView in about 8 years and the SqlDataSource is also getting dated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the parameter values in your code behind.

```
SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters.Add("Content", "ABC");
SqlDataSource1.DeleteParameters.Add("Title", "XYZ");
```

Comment: What do i replace ABC and XYZ with?

Comment: These would be your filter values. Honestly, it doesn't make a lot of sense to be filtering by these in a delete situation. You would like delete records based on a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

Yoy need to set the DataKeyNames property on the gridview  control to GradeID

[Check answer 1](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/gridview-control-delete-error-must-110142.aspx)